# geopandas segmentation fault with shapefile

Tags: python, pandas, shapefile, geopandas

I am trying to use geopandas but am struggling to fix this segmentation fault error. I am using the [US census bureau shapefiles](https://www.census.gov/geographies/mapping-files/time-series/geo/carto-boundary-file.html) but struggling I can't find a solution that works online. I can have my conda list available if needed.

```
>>> import geopandas as gpd
>>> fp = 'cb_2018_us_state_20m/cb_2018_us_state_20m.shp'
>>> contiguous_usa = gpd.read_file(fp)
[2]    2258 segmentation fault  python
```

Comment: can you post that `conda list`?

Comment: @marinfleis I wasn't sure what the best way to share large snippets would be so I through it into a google doc https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gaHqfwz6nLdkjCGnbMZctFDY1i4suv6YKQgsfYlGh9Q/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Try reinstalling geopandas from `conda-forge` channel. `conda install -c conda-forge geopandas`